# Displaying min() value in array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I want to display 10 highest figure and 10 lowest figure in a multi-dimensional array. 
I have figured out way to display the maximum figure using `max()`, but when I use `min()`, the least less value get looped again and again for 10 times e.g 2.

How can I reuse my code to display minimum value in my array?

```
  $totalCustomer = count($customerArray);
$postion = 0;
foreach ($customerArray as $custom) {
    $postion = $postion + 1;
    if($totalCustomer - $postion < 9){
        $top[] = $custom['spend'];
        $maxprice = max($top);

        echo "Max spend price is ". $maxprice. "<br>";
    }                              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `usort`:

```
/* Sort the array the value of 'spend' */
usort($customerArray, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['spend'] == $b['spend']) {
        return 0;
    } else if ($a['spend'] > $b['spend']) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});

/* The top 10 elements are now on top of the array */    
$top = array_slice($customerArray, 0, 10);

/* If we reverse the array using array_reverse() the 
   smallest items are on top */
$low = array_slice(array_reverse($customerArray), 0, 10);
```

Comment: here is my [complete code](http://pastebin.com/xA7i03aH), can you explain me what you did. seems too fast for me. what if i want to display cross section of business or any other array.

Comment: Basically everything is wrong with your code which makes it hard to explain. I've added comments which explain what I'm doing. Note, that you probably need to show more effort if you don't understand something, especially if you are new to that. Have you read the manual pages of `usort()`, `array_slice()` and `array_reverse()`? If not, you should start there.

Comment: i ran your code but its giving me lots of error like **usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given** **array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given** etc

Comment: You need to declare `$array` or use `$customerArray` instead. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: @he2mgl hehe, thought so. thats why i said it was advance for me. Is it possible to cross-section based on the same array too?

Comment: What do you mean with `cross-section-based`?

Comment: Note that I'm on my way home. I'll have a look here again in ~30minutes

Comment: like display common ones, suppose 3 people have 'busniess' => 'hardware store', and i display there ['spend'] value only.

Comment: @hek2mgl Upvote for you politeness and courtesy! You deserve!

Answer (score 1):

@hek2mgl answer is a good one. But you can take advantage of PHP array's indexes to avoid sorting and gaining performance.

```
$prices = [];

foreach ( $customerArray as $custom )
{
    // This approach uses your price as an ordering index, and supposes two decimal points
    $index = intval( $custom['spend'] * 100 );
    $prices[$index] = $custom['spend'];
}


// Showing lowest 10 prices
$top = array_slice( $prices, 0, 10 );

// Showing top 10 prices
$low = array_slice( array_reverse( $prices ), 0, 10 );
```

Comment: Basically I like your idea. Have you tried whether that is faster, or do you just think it is faster?

Comment: @Paulocoghi can u explain the code. i don't see the output of the code. its blank.

Comment: @hek2mgl I have tried this approach only in c++ and it is always faster, because it doesn't make comparisons.

I am curious to see how it performs in PHP and, probably, it will be in an O(n) instead of O(0) due to PHP Array implementation (also faster than any other comparison method)

Comment: A foreach loop is relatively expensive in PHP (definitely when compared to a for loop in C). On the other hand my solution requires to call the anonymous function again and again. Without having tested it so far, it looks like yours is indeed faster, would like to see a benchmark.. Don't have much time yet. However +1 for idea, its good! :)

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that, you can use `array_map()` or `array_reduce()` to replace the foreach loop. This would be even faster I guess. You should try it.

Comment: Sure! Both `array_map()` and `array_reduce()` presents O(n) complexity and helps making the solution even faster :) Thanks a lot!